# Data Cloud Data Stream to S3?

Tags: cdp

Is there a way to have a data stream, which is in Data Cloud, pushed to a S3 bucket? There doesnt appear to be any documentation around this.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing data from Data Cloud to S3 is possible using the Segmentation and Activation capabilities. If you're wanting everything from the Data Stream, you'd need to just ensure that the segment you're creating is broad enough that is covers all the data you're ingesting.

The [Segmentation and Activation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/customer-360-audiences-segmentation?trail_id=explore-customer-360-audiences) Trail covers setting up an S3 Activation Target which is what you'd need to set up.

One of the key restrictions around this though is that you're limited to the standard 12 or 24 hour publishing cycles for the segments that you're creating.

If the data you're ingesting in real-time, an alternative would also be to use [Data Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_data_actions_CDP.htm&type=5), and specifically a [Webhook Data Action Target](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.c360_a_create_a_data_action_target_of_webhook_type.htm&type=5). With this you'd be able to use a Lambda function to write the events received to S3 in real time.